# How does the normality assumption change a parametric test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, nonparametric

I understand *what* a parametric test assumes: normality, equal variance, homoscedasticity,  etc. Bu how does this assumption change the setup of the actual test, as compared to a non-parametric test? For example, what step(s) can be skipped?

Comment: Maybe you should focus on a specific test. Only a small proportion of parametric tests assume these things.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you make an assumption about the distribution/some other properties you ADD some information to your test and hence you have more power, the probability to reject null given the alternative.